# CSS Relative and Absolute Postioning

Tags: asp.net, css, positioning

I am using css relative and absolute to position a div of links inside of a picture on my website.  The problem is when I zoom in/out of the webpage (or view the webpage on a phone) the links move left/right. How can I get the links to remain in the same position on the picture?

Website: www.cclandscaping.org

CSS Code:

```
.header-links {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: auto;
        right: 25%;
        top: 43%;
        font-size: x-large;
    }
    .header-pic {
        position: relative;
    }
```

Picture and links code:

```
<div class="header-pic"; style="text-align: center">
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Header.png" />
        <div class="header-links">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink>
                &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/About.aspx">About</asp:HyperLink>
                &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/References.aspx">References</asp:HyperLink>
                &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
```

Comment: The provided HTML/CSS is not enough to reproduce the "problem":  http://tinker.io/8568f

Comment: Where's the CSS for the header class? Have you tried the header-links class in the nested div?

Comment: Oh sorry, that wasn't supposed to be in there...  Code is changed and the problem persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.header-pic` must have width. I also centered it:

```
.header-pic {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1100px;
}
```

Comment: I've verified that this will solve your problem but you need to adjust the positioning of .header-links now that a size is applied otherwise the links will be sitting more centered.  Try changing .header-links to 'right: 7%' (adjust to your liking)

Answer (score 0):

The relative links should be within an absolute.

Ie. Swap relative with absolute in your css.

```
.header-links {
        position: relative;
        z-index: auto;
        right: 25%;
        top: 43%;
        font-size: x-large;
    }
    .header-pic {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

The links won't be able to move outside of the absolute div.

Comment: This makes the links move with the header which is what I want, but the links are no longer on top of the header.  I want to be able to position them on top of the header.